# Deploy Blender to Azure App

Tags: python, azure, blender, azure-api-apps

I have copied `Blender.exe` and all associated files into `Azure API App` then try to run it with my custom Python script like this (using `System.Dianostics.Process`()):

> blender.exe --background --python myscript.py

But can not get it run properly. Note that it works fine in my local IIS.

So the question is does Azure App support to run Blender?
(as Blender may need to have GPU support machine to run, and Azure does not support GPU yet)

And if yes, so how to see what error return from the `blender.exe` command? (I am unable to remote desktop to `Azure Api App` to run the command manually unfortunately)

UPDATED:

I can run blender script above successfully using `Azure Console` command line by hand.
But when run the script using code `System.Diagnostics.Process`() it got this error from StandardError stream:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
>
> OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Comment: I haven't used it but there is a [project on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-apps-blender) to run blender on azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MinhNguyen, According to the wiki [page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) of Kudu, Azure App Services which include Api App are not support scenarios using GDI+ because of Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions, but blender works with `gdi32`. So unfortunately blender can not work on Azure Api App, please consideration for Azure Cloud Service or Virtual Machine for blender.

---

**Update**:
As @MinhNguyen comments said, blender can be run manually in Kudu console, although it seems blender works with GDI because of compiling blender need gdi32.lib. So the solution for the issue is that package blender.exe and related python script as a webjob to run on Azure.

Comment: Thanks. But why I can still run the Blender script in Azure Api App using command line in Kudu debug console?

Comment: @MinhNguyen, I searched that compiling blender need gdi32.lib, but I'm not sure that only run blender with cmd whether need gdi. If you can manually run it in Kudu console, I think you can try to package them as a webjob to run.

Comment: Thanks @PeterPan. I was moving it to WebJob and it works.